# Where can I find documentation on aarch64-poky-linux-ld?

Tags: linux, yocto, nxp-microcontroller

This question follows on from [Can you tell me what "crus" means in "LDFLAGS = crus $@"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751327/can-you-tell-me-what-crus-means-in-ldflags-crus)

Since my error message is "aarch64-poky-linux-ld: cannot find crus: No such file or directory",
where can I find documentation on aarch64-poky-linux-ld?

Best regards,

Next questions: [How do I link in needed libraries to a new layer in Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66860929/how-do-i-link-in-needed-libraries-to-a-new-layer-in-yocto)
[How do I link librt and libpthread to a new layer in Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873887/how-do-i-link-librt-and-libpthread-to-a-new-layer-in-yocto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Linux systems I know of use GNU `ld` as their linker, part of the `binutils` package, and it has a [complete manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/).  The `aarch64-poky-linux-` prefix is a [target triplet](https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet), used to identify which cross-compilation target this particular `ld` executable is for.

However, all I think it will tell you is that a string which is not part of an option (starting with `-` or `--`) will be treated as an input file.  So the message just reports that it is trying to use `crus` as an input file but it doesn't exist.  That's not surprising because as was pointed out on your other question, `crus` appears to be meant as options to the `ar` program, not for `ld` at all.  They don't make sense in an `LDFLAGS` variable.  So you will need instead to debug whatever makefile or script decided to try to pass those "options" to `aarch64-poky-linux-ld` in the first place.